# how to modify the line containing the prefix numbers with sed or awk

Tags: regex, git, bash, awk, sed

i'm sorry if the title make confusing, i need help in bash scripting, i'm use git bash in windows and i have csv file to modified, example below.

**Input**

```
1 example1
200 example2
example3
108 example4
```

**desire output**

```
$1 example1
$200 example2
example3
$108 example4
```

Could anyone help to do this in awk or sed ? thank you

Comment: You really should have a go with the program before you ask for help here. Google will give you many how-tos and you could try it and then bring it here with questions like "why doesn't my code work to get this intended result".

Comment: I'm sorry for this, because I'm really confused search for a keyword to find out about it.
and I was already looking for many times, but unfortunately I have not found what I was looking for, and in the end I asked here
once again, I am sorry.
thank you for your advice, the future I will try harder before asking here.

Comment: try `how to use awk` or `how to use sed` in google.

Comment: Ok Shawn Mehman, it seems I also have to read a lot of documentation, once again I'm sorry, I just made this place a shortcut to quickly solve the code, without Understand what is written, once again thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this,

```
sed 's/^\([[:digit:]]\)/\$\1/' file
```

- `^` start of the line anchor which matches the start of the line boundary.
- `[[:digit:]]` POSIX char class which matches only digit characters. Here it matches exactly one digit character. So this will only affect the lines which has a digit at the start.

Comment: sadly, @Avinash Raj, you seem to have given him a fish but there was no learning how to fish here today. Not your fault, and thanks for the answer.

Comment: or `sed 's/^[[:digit:]]/\$&/' file`